# Definition and Assignment of Pointers to functions at global and local scope

Tags: c++, function-pointers, global, definition, program-entry-point

A quick question I hope. I would like to know why the line commented out below causes an error when placed at the global level while it works fine when placed inside the main function?

Many Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool compare(const int &v1, const int &v2)  {
    if (v1 < v2) { 
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


bool (*pf5)(const int &v1, const int &v2);
//pf5 = compare;


int main() {
    int v1 = 5;
    int v2 = 6;
    pf5 = compare;

    bool YesNo1 = compare(v1, v2);
    cout << YesNo1 << endl;
    bool YesNo3 =pf5(v1, v2);
    cout << YesNo3 << endl;

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: It's generally a good idea to include the compiler error when posting about them.  They *usually* tell you what the problem is...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't perform assignments except inside functions. You can however perform initialisations:

```
bool (*pf5)(const int &v1, const int &v2) = compare;
```

Comment: interesting - that is something I didnt know. And from my tests it seems that the rule you mention applies to all types, not to pointers to functiosn only.  Thanks a lot for your reply. it was much more helpful than I could possible hope. #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int paolo;
 paolo = 5;
    
    int main() {
     cout << paolo << endl;
  
  
     return 1;
    }

Comment: @Random Yes it does. You cannot write any old C++ code anywhere you fancy - apart from definitions and initialisations, it must ALL go inside a function.

Comment: got you. I am sure that knowing that will avoid many headaches in the future. Thanks again.

Comment: @RandomCPlusPlus: `int paolo; paolo = 5;` works because `paolo = 5;` is interpreted as a definition with initialization (which is different from assignment). The definition has default type `int`, which is consistent with the previous declaration of `int paolo;`, so there is no conflict. In contrast, `bool (*pf5)(const int &v1, const int &v2);` declares pf5 to be a pointer to a function. Then `pf5 = compare;` is a definition of pf5 as `int`, so it is inconsistent with the previous declaration.